# Jquery replace value in a string and call function with args whose name is the value without using eval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this function to replace value in a string and call functions whose name is the value.

```
$(function() {

    var str = "Homer drank {{countBeers}} beers";

    function countBeers() {
        console.log(this);
        return 10 + 10;
    }

    function convert(str) {
        console.log(this);

        str = "'" + str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, "' + $1.call(this) + '") + "'"; 

        OR

        str = "'" + str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, "' + $1(this) + '") + "'";

        return eval(str);
    }

    var output = convert.call(this, str);

    $('body').append(output);  //Homer drank 20 beers

});
```

This seems to work fine, but I would not use eval.
You can do it any other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object with the function.

```js
function convert(str) {
    return str.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (_, f) {
        return op[f] ? op[f]() : f;
    });
}

var str = "Homer drank {{countBeers}} beers",
    op = { countBeers: function () { return 10 + 10; } };

console.log(convert(str));
```

Comment: Sounds great, but how can I pass parameters (this or other) to the functions?

Comment: which parameter do you need?

Comment: this or something else. My goal would be to do it this way {{ countBeers(this, foo, bar) }}

Comment: in this case i suggest to use [template litrals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) of es6. you could insert `this` in `op[f](this)`.